# Python Command Prompt Disappears when trying to Import

Tags: python, import, command-prompt

When attempting to import a library (it is the "neuron" library for running [numerical neuronal simulations](http://www.neuron.yale.edu/neuron/)) in the interpreter, I simply lose the command prompt indefinitely without an error:

```
kjb:~ ken$ python
Python 2.7.8 |Anaconda 1.9.0 (x86_64)| (default, Jul  2 2014, 15:36:00) 
...
>>> import neuron
_
```

The underscore is meant to represent the cursor.

I understand that this is likely a problem within *neuron* itself, as other modules such as *math* import with no problem, however I am wondering how I should proceed to figure out what is wrong? I am fairly inexperienced here.

Thanks!

Comment: Try ctrl-c and see what the stack trace says. You could then search neuron + the error message.

Comment: You could also try this: python -m trace --trace your_prog.py

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it's **easier to use python with NEURON by starting NEURON first** with the -python flag:

```
nrniv -python
```

or

```
nrgui -python
```

This starts NEURON with python interpreter:

```
NEURON -- VERSION 7.4 (1373:f15dcfc7847b) f15dcfc7847b
Duke, Yale, and the BlueBrain Project -- Copyright 1984-2015
See http://www.neuron.yale.edu/neuron/credits
```

Where you can then run python commands:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=6, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>> quit()
```

The **more challenging route is to start python first, and then import the NEURON library**:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.11 (default, Dec  5 2015, 14:44:47) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import neuron
NEURON -- VERSION 7.4 (1373:f15dcfc7847b) f15dcfc7847b
Duke, Yale, and the BlueBrain Project -- Copyright 1984-2015
See http://www.neuron.yale.edu/neuron/credits
```

To start python and then import NEURON library, you need to:

**On MS Windows, [install PyNEURON](https://www.neuron.yale.edu/phpBB/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2501)**

```
pip install PyNEURON
```

**On other OS's, compile NEURON from source and setup NEURON python library**

1. [Compile NEURON from source with python support](http://www.neuron.yale.edu/neuron/download/getstd)
2. [Setup the NEURON library for python](http://www.davison.webfactional.com/notes/installation-neuron-python/)